# how to build apk create old version app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, build, apk, flutter-android

I am trying to build my release app in Flutter and when I run:

`flutter run`

everything works fine in debugging and test mode. But when I was trying to build a release app with:

`flutter build apk`

it creates an old first-release app of mine. That I created before and I try to reset the computer reset android and everything but not work what can I do to reset it and clear the cache?
I'm trying almost to delete and reset everything but they don't work.
What command that I have to run to fix it and create new version release apk

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The solution is easy.
Just run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and then run `flutter build apk` after that and it generates the updated app apk.
If you want to install it directly just run `flutter install` after the build command.

Answer (score 21):

run these command

```
flutter clean
```

and after that

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: `flutter build apk --debug` also works

Answer (score 7):

To all the beginners If you wish to release an apk of a flutter app just do:
**flutter run --release** 
(and make sure to connect your device to a phone)
steps to ensure your phone is connected:
1. enable usb debugging mode in your phone
2.click on version number of your phone in system settings to enter into developer mode 
3. change the phone mode to transferring file mode

**After you run the command 
go to build->apps->output->apk**

Answer (score 4):

**First clean project with command:**

```
flutter clean
```

**Re-build the project:**

```
flutter pub get
```

**Run the command to build the APK:**

```
flutter build apk
```

The generated APK file(s) will be located in the folder:  `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/`

---

*You can also specify different options to customize the build process:*

- To build a release APK:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

- To build a debug APK:

```
flutter build apk --debug
```

- To build a release APK with multiple ABIs:

```
flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi
```

- To build an APK for a specific target platform:

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform android-arm64
```

Official Flutter documentation for reference: [Build an APK](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk)

Answer (score 2):

Run this command for making a bundle.

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

Answer (score 1):

If `flutter clean`  and `flutter build apk` also generates apk with old version code in your pubspec.yaml change the version like this version: `1.0.2+2`
Before + it is your version name and after +  sign it is your version code

**NOTE:** Your new version number should be in the place of 2. Or you can use different format such as `1.2+2`

Answer (score 1):

You can run `flutter clean` Then run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` to split the apk. It will build three apks and you can find them in `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can be done easily by Android Studio

Comment: This not the right way. Make sure you follow https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android