# Flutter Android - Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run the command "`flutter build appbundle --verbose`" to generate the android version of my app and i am receiving the error "`Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1`".

I don't know yet a lot of things about gradle and your dependencies to each package, I have read some stack-overflow answers, refactored the `bundle.properties` file among other things without success. Here is my build information:

`flutter build appbundle --verbose` part of output

```
:flutter_secure_storage:bundleLibCompileRelease [        ]         
********************************************************* [        ] WARNING: This version of firebase_messaging will break your Android
build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX. [    
]          See xxxxxxx for more information on the
problem and how to fix it. [        ]          This warning prints for
all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be
unrelated. [        ]         
********************************************************* [        ] 90 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 84 up-to-date [ +426 ms] Running
Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (completed in 11,3s) [   +4 ms]
"flutter appbundle" took 20.362ms.
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:751 :5) <asynchronous
suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:494:14 ) <asynchronous
suspension>
#3      buildAppBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/app_bundle.dart:43:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/bui ld_appbundle.dart:47:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/fl utter_command.dart:490:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure(dart:async-patch/async_patc h.dart:71:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl .dart:678:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#12     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#13     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure(dart:async/future_impl.dart:5 52:7)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure(dart:async/zone.dar t:963:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116: 13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dar t:173:5)
```

Android (parent) build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
  project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
  project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
//solving error
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
      if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
        details.useVersion "27.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

App (child) build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new Exception("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

/*    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }*/

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "br.com.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file('key.jks')
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            //useProguard true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner: 1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Flutter / Dart pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  fluro: ^1.5.0
  share: ^0.6.1+1
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.4.2
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
  intl: ^0.15.8
  expandable: ^3.0.0+1
  url_launcher: ^5.1.2
  keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.2.1+1
  keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.6
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.0
  image_picker: 0.6.0+17
  image_cropper: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: 0.5.3+4
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.22.2
  dio: 3.0.3
  path: 1.6.4
  uuid: 2.0.2
  flutter_app_badger: ^1.0.3+2
  badges: ^1.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.4
  #device_id: ^0.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Do you all have any suggestion to solve this problem?

I have also tried to migrate to AndroidX without success.

Comment: add these `android.useAndroidX=true` and 
`android.enableJetifier=true`to `android/gradle.properties`. let me know if that works.

Comment: maybe you need to take a look at this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695393/flutter-build-apk-create-old-version-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695393/flutter-build-apk-create-old-version-app)

Comment: hi @ArashMohammadi, i have already done..."org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
#extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate
android.enableR8=false
"

Comment: @HaironChaviano, it doesnt look to be what i need :/

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's a minor issue, Run "Flutter clean" and then "Flutter build appbundle" or "Flutter build apk".

That should fix the issue

Comment: Hey thats not working I tried it twice ..Please suggest any other method

Answer (score 0):

I also hit this issue today. I deployed two apps, with different version of gradle version. Try this. in `android/build.gradle` try to use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1`, seems like gradle 3.5 gives problem for flutter to build appbundle successfully.

But if you read [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38934#issuecomment-523548897) the appbundle is actually created in `build/app/outputs/bundle/<build-type>`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the correct key.properties file
my problem was just this, the name should be without -keystore.jks

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=/Users/USERNAME/upload-keystore.jks
```